# Saving position of draggable jQuery without id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have searched for solutions to this but they all involved having named id's in your program. Mine doesn't. It involves having a page where users can create their own lists which means that I cannot know beforehand how many lists they will have and what they should be named.

However, I have tried to do this in a loop to pass the list name as the id but without succes. Here is my Ruby code that creates the lists on the page:

```
<p>
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
  <div data-listname="<%= list.name %>" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
  <h2><%= link_to list.name, list, "data-role" => "button", "data-inline" => "true", "data-mini" => "true" %></h2>
  <div id="description"> <%= list.description %></div> <br><br>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_list_url(list), "data-role" => "button", "data-inline" => "true", "data-mini" => "true", "data-icon" => "gear" %> <%= link_to "Delete", list_url(list), :method => :delete, "data-role" => "button", "data-inline" => "true", "data-mini" => "true", "data-icon" => "alert" %>
<br>
</div>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

And this is the Javascript/jquery code that enables dragging:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function() 
{
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ snap: true, grid: [ 10,10 ] });
});
```

I'm thinking of saving the position of each list in a cookie/localstorage but I have no idea how to do that individually for each list. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i will give the step by step process to do that.

1) In the above code, add some dynamically primary key or something as Id of the div

2) when ever you drag, handle its start or stop event to save the position in a global variable.

3)when ever you drag just appened the information to the global variable, once done save that in local veriable or cookie by converting global variable to string form. when ever required parse using JSON2.JS library, and use JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() method for the same.

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: There already is a dynamically generated id in the div of the list as presented as "<%= list.name %>". The problem is that I cannot figure out how to pass this id to the start/stop event and save/parse the position.

Comment: Any events in javascript you take it will have a parameter e, so in your start and stop method start : function(e){ using the "e" variable you can get the id of the dragged element}

Comment: try using function(e) { var id = e.currentTarget.id; }; this is how you can get id of the element.@Rezk

Comment: Okay, this is what I tried:

$( document ).on( "pageinit", function(e)  
{  
 var id = e.currentTarget.id;  
 $( "id").draggable({  
  stop: function(event, ui){  
   dragposition = ui.position;  
  }  
 });  
});  

However, this broke the drag functionaility as nothing can be dragged anymore in the page. Though the function is now more verbose than necessary, it still has the basic functionality of dragging in it. I wonder why it broke.

Comment: @Rezk See you have written $("id"), change that to $("#"+id), as it is a ID selector should start with #.